# How can I set my title in the URL or routing module using Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I only need something like this

**home.routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: 'car/<any content>/:id', component: CarDetailComponent }
    ])
)
```

I did a quick check but I couldn't find any examle like this

Comment: by title you mean the browser title or a path param ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be placeholder like `/:title`, same as that of you did for `id`

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'car/:title/:id', component: CarDetailComponent }
])
```

For redirecting on above URL you could use `routerLink` directive with appropriate parameter.

```
[routerLink]="['car', title, id]"
```